# Set up three-quarter view?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Three quarter view -- if I understand correctly -- is used a lot in technical illustration. I am trying to make a technical illustration using Blender, and wonders how to setup such a view.

The default view looks a lot like three quarter view, although surprisingly I couldn't find any official statement to confirm that. And what if you adjust the camera while working, but want to get such a view in the end?

I am wondering how you guys deal with this. Do you keep adjusting so it looks OK? Or there are some accurate parameters to use? Thanks!

Comment: It would be difficult to give out uniform rotations and transforms for such a view as camera angles are all relative, can you achieve the desired view you want with your own adjustment? The best way to achieve this quickly is to get the correct view in the viewport and then hit Ctrl+Alt+0 to align the camera to it, that should make achieving this view and 10 second process :)

Comment: @NickBosse Thanks. I am aware of this "assign current view to camera" operation in blender. I was mainly wondering if there are industrial standards -- since this view is so commonly used in industrial design drawing, and in those countless 2.5D games. So seems there ain't.

Comment: I get what you are saying but yeah, in 2.5D games the camera angle is never the same, the developers always tweak it to the best possible view for the environment, camera angles aren't really something where it is one-size-fits-all even if it is a well used view as you mentioned. CAD programs will automatically set up diagonal orthographic views and thats about it. The point is, even if there was a benchmark angle or an industry standard, it probably wouldn't suit your scene/model anyway. Hope you achieve your desired angle :)

Comment: @NickBosse Hi Nick, what you said makes a lot of sense. Forget about technical standards, I have got a good angle :)